# Count "Word Order" with further optimization

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge

**Question**:
You are given `n` words. Some words may repeat. For each word, print its number of occurrences. The output order should correspond with the input order of appearance of the word.

**Sample Input**:

```
4
bcdef
abcdefg
bcde
bcdef
```

**Sample Output**

```
3
2 1 1
```

Here's what I came up with:

```py
n = int(input())
array = []
elements = {}
for index in range(n):
    value = input()
    if value not in array:
        array.append(value)
        elements[value] = 1
    else:
        elements[value] += 1

print(len(elements))
print(*(i for i in elements.values()), end=' ')
```

I stress tested it on [Try it Online](https://p.ip.fi/IwRU) with the [random string generator](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=10000&len=20&loweralpha=on&unique=off&format=html&rnd=new) and found the runtime to be around 1.98s. But I'm getting TLE on the coding platform. How do I improve the speed (bit offtopic - is there any other approach)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLE

You're probably getting a TLE because,

```
if value not in array:
```

Is a O(N) operation meaning it has to traverse the entire array (worst case) to check if the value exists in the array

I can understand why you felt the need to have an extra array, because of dictionaries are not ordered.

But you can make use of the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) module, to have an ordered dictionary!

## Other

1. join!

   ```
   print(*(i for i in elements.values()), end=' ')
   ```

   This can be done cleaner with joining the values instead of unpacking

   ```
   print(" ".join(map(str, e.values())))
   ```
2. Counter

   Python is often described as batteries included,

   Your `element` dictionary is the same the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

## Code

We can make an `OrderedCounter` class to combine these two and make get the most out of the included modules.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

c = OrderedCounter(input() for _ in range(int(input())))
print(len(c))
print(" ".join(map(str, c.values())))
```